How to map thermal image to temperature values?
I take pictures using a MicaSense Altum-PT camera which uses "320 x 256 FLIR Boson" as its thermal sensor. The saved thermal images are completely gray color (tif format). The raw pixel values are 16 bit (For example:31399,31436, 31415). From the metadata of the thermal image, I was able to extract Thermal Calibration Parameters: [1, 316.8, 1192951.5, 1509.95947265625, 1, 13831.46484375] using meta.get_item('XMP:ThermalCalibrationParameters').
I am wondering is there a python code to calculate the temperature of all pixels of an image? I found a python code from this link https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3321/~/flir-cameras---temperature-measurement-formula, but I am not sure how to interpret these 6 Thermal Calibration Parameters for this python code.
I appreciate any help in advance.
Abbas

Seems like a question the manufacturer should be able to answer.

@MarkSetchell Thank you for your comment. You are right, but I am not sure if they have provided a calibration equation for the thermal sensor since they recommended me to find the equation for Flir Boson camera. I am wondering is there any calibration equation for this sensor based on the thermal parameters that I extracted from the metadata ?
